# Firebase push to database in while loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, while-loop

Good day,

I am trying implement @mentions so users can @ other users.

Things are going great, I am just about done but I have run into trouble on the last part.

I am trying to loop through the users who were mentioned by using a regex to capture their username. I have this done, now my problem occurs in my loop.

Here is a look at what I am working with:

```
onPostPress = async () => {
  this.setState(
    {
      addingComment: true,
    },
    () => {

    const re = /(?:^|[ ])@([a-zA-Z]+)/gm;
    const str = this.state.usersCommentText;
    var m;

    let mentionsArr = [];

    //OBJECT TO STORE IN USERS NODE
    let men = {
      username: this.props.userData.username,
      profileImg: this.props.userData.profilePic || null,
    };

    //INITIALIZE MULTI-PATH UPDATE
    const mentions = {};

    while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
      if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
      }

    //THIS WORKS
      mentionsArr.push(m[1]);

    //THIS DOESN'T WORK :( 
     await firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users')
        .orderByChild('username')
        .equalTo(`${m[1]}`)
        .once('value', snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(child => {
            mentions[`/users/${child.key}/men`] = men;
          });
        });

    }
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref()
        .update(mentions);
  },
);
```

}
As you can see, I am looping through the tagged users, and trying to set the men object to the users node so I can then trigger a cloud function to send a notification to inform the user they have been mentioned.

When this is complete, I then proceed to push the comment - but I cant figure out why this does not work.

I am able to push to the array from the loop without any problems, but not to the firebase RTDB.

I'd love some help with this issue to get me going in the right direction, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//THIS DOESN'T WORK :(
firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users')
    .orderByChild('username')
    .equalTo(`${m[1]}`)
    .once('value', snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(child => {
            mentions[`/users/${child.key}/men`] = men;
        });
    });
```

"It doesn't work", because it is asynchronous. You need to `await` it before you do

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref()
    .update(mentions);
```

otherwise your `mentions` object will be empty when the `update` is executed.

I also think your `while` loop should not include that last part. You meant to build your `mentions` in the loop, and THEN do the `update`, no?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried adding await and async to the function, but it is saying I cant use keyword await outside of an async function. Would I need to change my while loop at all too in order for await to work in the function?

Comment: @hugger a simple `while` loop (or a `for` loop) is OK in async functions. You'd only have a problem if you used `forEach()` or other array methods. Can you show how you've added async+await?

Comment: I just updated my answer! I moved it outside of the render func to use async. @Stratubas

Comment: @hugger at your 6th line, `() => {` should be made async

Comment: Right on! That was the problem. Thanks for looking into that appreciate it!